# dbt_project.yml , +alias cannot pass the validation when using the dbt-jsonschema

Tags: visual-studio-code, dbt

I am using https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-jsonschema
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dbt-labs/dbt-jsonschema/main/schemas/dbt_project.json
to validate my dbt_project yaml file in vs code. but I don't know why it raises error in +alias,

> the error is Incorrect type. Expected "null".yaml-schema: Model
> configs

```
# Configuring models
models:
  lakehouse:
    staging:
      +materialized: 'ephemeral'
    foo:
      +tags: foo
      +database: foo
      sources:
        +materialized: "{{ 'table' if target.name in ['test', 'prod'] else 'view' }}" 
        mytest:
          +tags: mytest
          +schema: source_mytest 
          +docs:
            node_color: '#75a7cd'
          mytest_1_advertisers: 
            +alias: advertisers
```

Would you mind giving some advice?
Best regards